# Avoid line jump in an array iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this tiny piece of code:

```
print('Your cards are:')
for i in playerCards:
    print(i)
```

Produces the output I want:

```
Your cards are:
TD
6D
```

However, I want to avoid the line jumps between each iteration on the array. How can I produce this instead?

```
Your cards are: TD 6D
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify `end` keyword argument to print a space instead of a newline:

```
print('Your cards are:', end=' ')
for i in playerCards:
    print(i, end=' ')
```

Or, using only one `print` function call with argument unpacking:

```
print('Your cards are:', *playerCards)
```

Comment: You can actually just do: `print('Your cards are:', *playerCards)`.  This will work even if the arguments are not strings.

Comment: @iCodez, You're right. Thank you for the suggestion. I updated the answer accordingly. :)

Comment: Using argument unpacking seems better than specifying `end` because  if I do the same with another array it outputs in the same line. Thank you @iCodez and @falsetru

Comment: @xacobecm, With `end=' '`, you need to call additional `print()` after the loop to finish a line.